# Changing the value of a second drop down menu based on selection from another

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have two drop down menu's for age, age from, and age to. Values within these drop downs range from 17-50.

If from the first drop down, a user selects `25` then in the second box, the user can choose a value lower than that which would not be ideal, nor would it make sense. Is there a way to get the second drop down to begin after the selection from the first drop down? So if a user selects age `25` from the first drop down, the second drop down would begin from `26`.

Just as a further check, a user may go onto the second drop down first, selecting an option which would invalidate the above check. In such a case, is there also a way to only enable to second drop down after the first one has been selected?

Here is how my drop downs are defined:

```
Age from:
                            <select> 
                            <option value="none"></option>
                                <?php
                                    for ($i=17; $i<=50; $i++)
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                                </select>
                                to: 
                            <select> 
                            <option value="none"></option>
                                <?php
                                    for ($i2=18; $i2<=50; $i2++)
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $i2;?>"><?php echo $i2;?></option>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                                </select>
```

Comment: From a usability standpoint, I'd suggest only flagging it when they are both selected and don't make sense, rather than disabling. Disabling prevents the user from correcting them in any order.

Comment: Isn't that a perfect case for [range slider](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/sliders/rangeslider.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you can't have one without the other:

```
Age from:
<select id="age_a" onchange="checkages_a()"> 
    <option value="none"></option>
<?php
    for($i = 17; $i <= 49; ++$i) {
        echo "\t", '<option value="', $i, '">', $i, '</option>', "\n";
    }
?>
</select>
to: 
<select id="age_b" onchange="checkages_b()"> 
    <option value="none"></option>
<?php
    for($i = 18; $i <= 50; ++$i) {
        echo "\t", '<option value="', $i, '">', $i, '</option>', "\n";
    }
?>
</select>
```

**Version A**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var age_a = document.getElementById("age_a");
var age_b = document.getElementById("age_b");

function checkages_a() {
    var a = typeof(age_a.options[age_a.selectedIndex]) !== 'undefined' ? age_a.options[age_a.selectedIndex].value : 0;
    var b = typeof(age_b.options[age_b.selectedIndex]) !== 'undefined' ? age_b.options[age_b.selectedIndex].value : 0;
    if(b == 'none' || a > b)
        age_b.selectedIndex = age_a.selectedIndex - 1;
}

function checkages_b() {
    var a = typeof(age_a.options[age_a.selectedIndex]) !== 'undefined' ? age_a.options[age_a.selectedIndex].value : 0;
    var b = typeof(age_b.options[age_b.selectedIndex]) !== 'undefined' ? age_b.options[age_b.selectedIndex].value : 0;
    if(!b || b == 'none')
        age_b.selectedIndex = age_a.selectedIndex - 1;
    if(a == 'none' || b < a)
        age_a.selectedIndex = age_b.selectedIndex + 1;
}
</script>
```

**Version B**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var age_a = document.getElementById("age_a");
var age_b = document.getElementById("age_b");

function checkages_a() {
    var a = typeof(age_a.options[age_a.selectedIndex]) !== 'undefined' ? age_a.options[age_a.selectedIndex].value : 0;
    var b = typeof(age_b.options[age_b.selectedIndex]) !== 'undefined' ? age_b.options[age_b.selectedIndex].value : 0;
    if(b == 'none' || a >= b)
        age_b.selectedIndex = age_a.selectedIndex;
}

function checkages_b() {
    var a = typeof(age_a.options[age_a.selectedIndex]) !== 'undefined' ? age_a.options[age_a.selectedIndex].value : 0;
    var b = typeof(age_b.options[age_b.selectedIndex]) !== 'undefined' ? age_b.options[age_b.selectedIndex].value : 0;
    if(!b || b == 'none')
        age_b.selectedIndex = age_a.selectedIndex;
    if(a == 'none' || b <= a)
        age_a.selectedIndex = age_b.selectedIndex;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, this works great so far. Is there a way to tweak this a little? For example, if I choose the value `22` from `age_b` first, `age_a` will also have a value of `22`. Is there a way to get it so that if a value is chosen from `age_b` first, then `age_a` will always be -1 from the value of `age_b`, i.e. 21. I basically do not want two numbers of the same value to be visible at one time.

Comment: Here you go, buddy! Try version B to see if you like those results more.

Comment: After a little tweaking, I got it down to simply changing the first box to only output to 49 and removing the + 1 and - 1 from the functions to get the results you're after.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was after. I really appreciate the help, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```html
    From:
   <select id='select1'> 
    <option value="none" SELECTED>Select an Age</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
    <?php
     for ($i=17; $i<=50; $i++)
     {
     ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
     <?php
     }
    ?>
   </select>
 To:
   <select id='select2'> 
   <option value="none">Select an Age</option>
      
   </select>
   
<script>
 var sel1 = document.getElementById('select1');
 var sel2 = document.getElementById('select2');
 
 sel1.onchange = function(event)
 {
  var age = sel1.value|0;
  
  var max_age = 90;
  
  for(var i=sel2.options.length-1;i>0;--i)
  {
   sel2.remove(i);
  }
  
  if(age === 0 || isNaN(age) === true)
   return;
  
  for(var i=age;i<=max_age;++i)
  {
   var opt = document.createElement('option');
   opt.text = i;
   opt.value = i;
   sel2.add(opt);
  }
 }
</script>
```